# Apache Camel Enricher

Tags: apache-camel

Hi so I am learning Apache Camel and trying to create a very simple service that combines two XML files based on an ID and move the resulting file to a new location. There are multiple files in a direcotry so I need to filter it based on an ID.

Client XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client>
  <id>2</id>
  <firstName>Clark</firstName>
  <lastName>Kent</lastName>
  <netWorth>470</netWorth>
</client>
```

and Address XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<address>
  <id>3</id>
  <clients>
    <clientId>2</clientId>
  </clients>
  <city>New York</city>
</address>
```

So I would like to add the *city* element from the Address XML to the Client XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<client>
  <id>2</id>
  <firstName>Clark</firstName>
  <lastName>Kent</lastName>
  <netWorth>470</netWorth>
  <city>New York</city>
</client>
```

I've been reading about aggregators and enrichers, from what I understand an aggregator would combine all XML files in the directory(not really what I want) and an enricher would add a resource from another service but how do I filter out based on the id and add it to the XML structure and not just at the end.

Thanks, sorry this is probably really basic I just don't know it.

Comment: Because of the way Camel works, this isn't trivial. The first question is, what is going to trigger your route to start? You normally need some sort of trigger (message in a queue, timer, new file in a directory etc) to tell Camel to go off and do something. It's not clear (to me) what your program flow needs to look like.

Comment: This is for learning purposes so its really just me starting the route from a command line and moving and combining some files.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know , if you have resolved the issue yet , however , the answer to you question is - 
Aggregator has the method in Camel , where you can implement your logic , what to do with the old exchange and new exchange. In this case , you can get the ids of 2 exchanges and match it . Once matched , you can take the unmarshalled node(city) and add it to the parent xml .